# blank page after upgrading from 1.8 to 1.9.3.10

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, upgrade

I'm updating a `Magento 1.8 to 1.9.3.10` with the Magento connect.
Everything worked fine (or at least with no visible errors during the process), but now I have all the site as a blank page, and no access to admin (blank page also).

I've followed the guide to update Magento with the connect, and everything seems to work fine, but now what is happening is:

Any frontend page is loading "for a while" then display a blank page, but the HEAD section of HTML is printed (not all, but most).

While if I try to access a backend resource, a blank page (with only one byte) is displayed.

What I have actually is this, in the system.log there are these two lines:

```
2018-11-06T12:44:23+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(/home/ggservice/ivsanbernard/app/code/core/Mage/ConfigurableSwatches/Model/Resource/Catalog/Product/Type/Configurable/Product/Collection.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/ggservice/ivsanbernard/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2018-11-06T12:44:23+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Mage/ConfigurableSwatches/Model/Resource/Catalog/Product/Type/Configurable/Product/Collection.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/ggservice/ivsanbernard/app/code/local:/home/ggservice/ivsanbernard/app/code/community:/home/ggservice/ivsanbernard/app/code/core:/home/ggservice/ivsanbernard/lib:.:/usr/share/php:/home/ggservice/ivsanbernard/app/code/local/TypoStores/Less/Model')  in /home/ggservice/ivsanbernard/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
```

No error.log is created.

Interesting thing: if I misspelled a page, the 404 page is shown perfectly, with menu, footer, images, everything, no links is working from there.

do you have an clues? idea?

Comment: Did you flush the cache?

Comment: yes during the instalation, and to be sure I've deleted all the contents of var/cache/ now there are some other dirs inside, ifI delete them they are recrated upon page load. but nothign happens

Comment: Can you try setting `app/etc/modules/Mage_ConfigurableSwatches.xml` to false, clear cache and reload?

Comment: that has solved the problem!
may I ask you what is that and how I can recognize a similar problem? (luckily this is an update tryed in a dev server, but I will have to make it on production too).

Comment: Something went wrong with your update and you don't have the configurable swatches module properly installed. What happens when you go to Magento connect?

Comment: I cannot go in the admin... the admin is still a blank page, and no error.log is written,  but I can reach the /downloader/ dir, once there I can see the "magento connect", chekcing for updates there, no updates are highlighted...

Comment: Can you roll back your update? Something went wrong. Or can you just upload a fresh install of Magento? If you haven't modified any core files

Comment: yes, I could rollback, but I prefer to "find a solution" for update, I mean, I'll have to do it on production at a certain moment and I'll must finish it.
if i install a fresh 1.9 installtion and then copy:
database, local.xml, media dir and the theme files should I be ok?

Comment: 1. You should use git to push from Dev to live

Comment: 2. Don't copy anything just upload a fresh Magento and overwrite your core files

Comment: 3. My suspicion is that the update through Magento connect missed a package or something silly like that

Comment: well, actually I have copied a fresh installation on the server (replacing all the files present), then I have copied the app/etc/local.xml and all the theme files.

after doing the same as before  (setting app/etc/modules/Mage_ConfigurableSwatches.xml to false)
everything seems working fine :O

Comment: you shouldn't need to set it to False, I told you to do that before just because that's where the error is coming from

Comment: putting it to true makes the same error,  (blank page on frontend) but now I can see the backend properly.
is there a way to re-install the configurableswatches thing?

Comment: is there a way to "force reinstall" that specific module? maybe from connect?